# First attempts of range partition in mysql

Tags: mysql, automation, range, partitioning

so I'm trying partitions for the first time in mysql any help will be much appreciated. What I want the partition to do is get before less than cur date for partition 1, the next week in partition 2 and max value for partition 3.

```
create TABLE diagnostics_daily_device_summary (
ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
timestamp datetime,
```

--  there are other fields included but for the sake of the example I won't 
bother throwing them in

```
PRIMARY KEY (ID, timestamp)
        )
        PARTITION BY RANGE (yearweek(timestamp))(
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (yearweek(curdate())),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (yearweek(date_add(curdate(), interval 7 day))),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN maxvalue
);
```

I need to maintain the last 3 weeks of data that's why I'm breaking it down into yearweek format.

When I run the query the error message I'm getting is this

Error Code: 1064. Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near '), PARTITION p201547 VALUES LESS THAN (yearweek(date_add(curdate(), interval 7 d' at line 70

I'm not too sure how to fix it.

Additionally I want to add a new week every week and drop the last week, I got this line of code from an online source

```
USE demotimeparts;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rotateTimePartition;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE rotateTimePartition (newPartValue DATETIME)
BEGIN
        DECLARE keepStmt VARCHAR(2000) default @stms;
        DECLARE partitionToDrop VARCHAR(64);

    SELECT 201501
    INTO partitionToDrop
        -- FROM SCHEMA_NAME.partitions
        WHERE table_schema='SCHEMA_NAME'
        AND tabe_name='diagnostics_daily_device_summary'
        AND partition_ordinary_position=1;
    SET @stmt = CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE diagnostics_daily_device_summary DROP PARTITION' ,     partitionToDrop);
    PREPARE pStmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE pStmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE pStmt;

    SET @stmt = CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE diagnostics_daily_device_summary ADD PARTITION (PARTITION Y',
                        DATE_FORMAT(newPartValue, '%Y%m%d'),
                        ' VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS(\'', 
                         DATE_FORMAT(newPartValue, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                         '\')))');

    PREPARE pStmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE pStmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE pStmt;

    SET @stmt = keepStmt;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

Like I said any help will be greatly appreciated! thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The "timezone" 'error' has to do with not being sure which week a particular time is in.  If the timezone changes, some data could be in the wrong partition, thereby making `SELECTs` give the wrong answer.

Also, `CURDATE()` would be evaluated at the time of the `CREATE TABLE`.  I suspect this in not what you wanted.

Since you do want to drop old data, etc, I suggest you simply go with days or weeks and use constant dates (using `TO_DAYS()`).  Look at http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for details on how to do the rotation and tips on other issues.